# Grunt watch task failing to transpile ES6 code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, grunt-babel

I'm using grunt and grunt-babel to transpile ES6 code whenever I change an es6 file. However, it seems like I have an error in one of those files, as I get this message when I make a change

```
Waiting...
>> File "scripts/test.es6.js" changed.
Running "babel:files" (babel) task
Warning: scripts/actions.es6.js: Unexpected token (38:5) Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.
Completed in 0.758s at Mon Sep 14 2015 20:11:53 GMT-0700 (PDT) - Waiting...
```

I have a few questions.

1. scripts/test.es6.js is a correct ES6 file, yet the ES5 version of it doesn't appear in my output folder when it is changed because of an error in scripts/actions.es6.js - why?
2. How do I find this error in my ES6 code?
3. Why isn't the force flag causing this to compile?

Thanks

This is test.es6.js

```
class Person {                                          // The 'class' keyword
    constructor(name, age) {                            // Constructors
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

class Developer extends Person {                        // The 'extends' keyword
    constructor(name, age, ...languages) {              // Rest parameters
        super(name, age);                               // Super calls
        this.languages = [...languages];                // The spread operator
    }
    printLanguages() {                                  // Short method definitions
        for(let lang of this.languages) {               // The for..of loop
            console.log(lang);
        }
    }
}

let me = new Developer("James", 23, "ES5", "ES6");     // Block scoping hello
```

This is actions.es6.js

```
/*
 * Action types
 */

export const REQUEST_DISTRICTS = 'REQUEST_DISTRICTS';

export function requestDistricts(geoState) {
    return {
        type: REQUEST_DISTRICTS,
        geoState
    };
}

export const RECEIVE_DISTRICTS = 'RECEIVE_DISTRICTS';

export function receiveDistricts(geoState, json) {
    return {
        type: RECEIVE_DISTRICTS,
        geoState,
        receivedAt: Date.now(),
        districts: json.data.districts.map(district => district.data)
    }
}

export function fetchDistricts(geoState) {

    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(requestDistricts(geoState));
        var districtsDfd = $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/districts/",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json"
        });
        var demographiesDfd = [];
        $.when(districtsDfd).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXhr){
            if (data) {
                _.each(data, datum => 
                    var id = datum.id;
                    demographiesDfd.push($.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/district/${id}/demography"));
                );
            }
        });
        $.when(...demographiesDfd).done(result =>
            //so I have demographic data right now. 
            dispatch(receiveDistricts(geoState, result));
        );
    }
}
```

The error is happening on var id = datum.id;

Comment: Can you add code from `test.es6.js` file

Comment: It's up there, I've also added code from actions.es6.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> scripts/test.es6.js is a correct ES6 file...

Yes, but `scripts/actions.es6.js` isn't. The line `Warning: scripts/actions.es6.js: Unexpected token (38:5) Used --force, continuing.` is telling you that `actions.es6.js` has an unexpected token. E.g., it cannot be compiled. That's stopping the Babel task. Apparently, Babel is compiling `actions.es6.js` before `test.es6.js` and bombing when it finds the error in `actions.es6.js`.

> How do I find this error in my ES6 code?

Look at line 38, character 5 of `actions.es6.js`. That's what the `(38:5)` in the error message is pointing out. Fix the error there, and Babel will be able to continue compiling.

> Why isn't the force flag causing this to compile?

The `--force` flag just tells Grunt to keep going, but *Babel's* already failed.

---

You've posted your code for `actions.es6.js`, the bug is indeed near line 38 (it's on line 37, but it's common for an error not to actually occur until the next line). You need `{` at the end of line 37 and `}` before the `);` on line 40:

```
_.each(data, datum => {
    var id = datum.id;
    demographiesDfd.push($.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/district/${id}/demography"));
});
```

...or if you're not going to use `id` for anything other than the one place in the template string, you can keep it a one-liner:

```
_.each(data, datum => demographiesDfd.push($.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/district/${datum.id}/demography")));
```

With an arrow function, if you have multiple statements, you must use braces. In general, I recommend using braces for any arrow function that isn't one *short* expression (for *me*, it has to be short enough to be on the `=>` line, but others have a different view). E.g., this is fine:

```
someArray.map(entry => entry.prop);
```

...but when you get into things that are much longer than that, it's going to be clearer to either break it out into a named function, or use a block and `return`.

Comment: yes..test.es6.js is a correct ES6 file, I know this because when I remove the other files and make a change, I get es5 JS transpiled. Also, the warning says scripts/actions.es6.js has the problem.

Comment: Also, how do I know what error I'm making? Where can I get that information?

Comment: @praks5432: Sorry, missed the difference in filename.

Comment: ohhh so babel fails as soon as it finds an error in ONE script?

Comment: @praks5432: I think so, yes. Updated the answer, apologies again on the filename thing.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion as to how to make grunt/babel give me more helpful error messages?

Comment: @praks5432: I don't see any "verbose" option for either grunt-babel or Babel itself. I've never felt the need, but I've only been using Babel a couple of months: It tells me what was wrong ("Unexpected token") and where (38:5), so that's usually enough: I go there in the source and see why it wasn't expecting what I had there.

Comment: @Tushar: Indeed, added.